# How to prove that a diophantine equation has only finitely many solutions in integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

In 1976 Tijdeman proved that the Catalan equation
$$
x^{p}-y^{q}=1
$$
has finitely many solutions in integers $x,y,p,q>1$ in his paper

- R. Tijdeman, *On the equation of Catalan*, Acta Arith. **29** (1976) pp 197–209 ([EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/205418))

He just found the following upper bound for $p$ and $q$ using Baker theorem in linear form in logarithm

\begin{align}
p& <2c_{9}(\log p)^{c_{10}}\\
q& <c_{1}(\log p)^{c_{2}}
\end{align}

I don't understand how these two inequalities for $p$ and $q$ give us that Catalan's equation has only a finite number of solution since he didn't give an upper bound for $x,y$.

Also in 1993, Overholt showed that Brocard equation
$$
n!+1=m^{2}
$$
has finitely solution if Szpiro's conjecture is true.
He just found that $n<4^{\epsilon}e $.
I don't understand how this upper bound for $n$ make us say that the Brocard equation has finitely many solutions?

I ask if a finding of an upper bound for a
least one variable of an arbitrary Diophantine equation is enough to prove that it has only finitely many solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$? If yes does the upper should do not depend on the other variable of that Diophantine equation?

*Edit* I need to answer the third question just .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings%27s_theorem

Comment: Please restrict to one question per post (standard MO policy). I answered your first question below.

Comment: @Ycor which theorem do  you mean

Comment: YCor meant that Faltings' theorem (that YCor linked for you) also implies that, for given $p$ and $q$, there are only finitely many solutions in $x$ and $y$. Baker's theorem mentioned in my response has the advantage of providing an effective bound for $x$ and $y$ (in terms of $p$ and $q$), unlike Faltings' theorem.

Comment: For the Brocard equation, for each $n$, how many values of $m$ are possible? Answer: 2. Hence if you bound $n$, then you know there are finitely many solutions. If you want an explicit bound, just use $m=\sqrt{n!+1}<\sqrt{4^\epsilon e+1}$ (assuming Szpiro).

Comment: @Joe Silverman so in the case of Diophantine equation of two variable it is enough to find an upper bound for one variable to show that the equation has finitely many solutions?

Comment: If a Diophantine equation has two variables $x$ and $y$, and you find an upper bound for $y$, then in effect you reduced the original equation to an equation in $x$. Now a one-variable Diophantine equation has finitely many solutions (unless it is degenerate like $x=x$), so the answer to your last question is "yes".

Comment: Consider the simple example $x^2-2y^2=1$, Abdo. This equation has infinitely many integer solutions, but if you bound either one of the variables, that automatically bounds the other, and results in there being only finitely many solutions.

Comment: Of course one needs to take my previous comment with a grain of salt. For example, consider the two-variable Diophantine equation $xy=y$ in positive integers. The only solutions are $x=1$ and $y$ arbitrary. So $x$ is bounded, yet there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @GH from MO what about the second part of the 3rd  equation does the upper bound should depend only on the variable of the original of it doesn't matter?

Comment: Please open a new question, keeping in mind that this site is for research level questions. (For general questions in mathematics see http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the initial remarks in the paper, one can restrict to $p,q\geq 5$. By Theorem A in the paper (which is a result of Baker's from 1969), $x$ and $y$ can be effectively bounded in terms of $p$ and $q$:
$$\max(|x|,|y|)<\exp\exp(5^{10}p^{10} q^{10q^3}).$$

Hence it suffices to bound $p$ and $q$.

Comment: but i mean in general is it enough to find an upper bound for only  one varible (3rd question )

Comment: @Abdo: The answer is "no". For example, the Fermat equation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ in positive integers implies that $n=1$ or $n=2$, but there are infinitely many solutions. BTW it is virtually impossible to say generalities that hold for all diophantine equations (cf. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Matiyasevich_theorem).

Comment: so for example if we want to prove that Brocard equation has  only finitely  solution we need to find upper bound for all the solution

Comment: @Abdo Yes, in some sense, but given the form of the Brocard equation, once you give an upper bound for one of the variables, it's trivial to get an upper bound for the other one. Similarly, on an elliptic curve, Siegel's theorem say $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ has only finite many solutions $(x,y)$ in integers, but effective versions often just write down a bound for $|x|$. However, it's possible sometimes to prove finiteness of solutions without bounding the size of the solutions. Indeed, Sigeel's original proof of his theorem has this form. The trick: Show $E(\mathbb Z)$ is a subset of a finite set ...

Comment: ... whose number of elements can be bounded, but for which you might not be able to find an upper bound for the size of the largest element. This is typical of proofs in Diophantine approximation, which is often used to study solutions to Diophantine equations.

Comment: @GH from MO ,Joe Silverman what about the upper bound .does the upper should depend on the variables of the same equation or it doesn't matter if they depend on other variables which have not related with the original equation?

Comment: @Joe Silverman what is the difference between finding an upper bound for each variable and finding an upper for $max(|n|, |m|)$?

Comment: @Abdo For an equation such as $n!+1=m^2$, an upper bound for one variable trivially gives an upper bound for the other variable. Similarly for an equation such as $x^3-2y^3=107$. But the original proof that $x^3-2y^3=107$ has finitely many solutions did not actually give an upper bound for $x$ and $y$. ...

Comment: ... Instead, it proved (roughly) that there were effectively computable constants $a$ and $b$ such **if* there were a  solution with $\max\{|x_0|,|y)_0|\}\ge a$, then every solution satisfies $\max\{|x|,|y|\}\le b\cdot\max\{|x_0|,|y)_0|\}$. This obviously shows that there are finitely many solutions, without given an explicit upper bound for the largest